# Querying ORM with WHERE clause - Eloquent/Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

The relevant code is at: https://gist.github.com/morganhein/9254678

I have nested resource controllers, which query similarly structured tables in a database.

If I go to www.example.com/v1/jobs/1/departments, I want to query all departments that are associated with job 1. However I cannot figure out how to do that using the ORM.

Help?

Comment: Your `jobs` table doesn't have a declared realationship with `departments`. You have to do this on your `Jobs` model.

Comment: I'm confused, in my jobs.php (model) it states:
     public function departments()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('Department');
 }

is that not what I need?

Comment: It's supposed to be. Doesn't work that way? If it doesn't, post your models code as well.

Comment: My models code is all in that gist, under Jobs.php and Department.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test, but I would suggest you to try something like this:

```
Route::resource('/v1/jobs/{id}/departments', 'DepartmentController');    
Route::resource('/v1/jobs', 'JobController');
```

After that, your DepartmentController methods will receive one argument, which is job id in your case. It is easier to use `find()` method if you are using `id` to retrieve any specific model. When you found the model you can get access to related models.

```
class DepartmentsController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index($jobId)
    {
        Clockwork::startEvent('List_Default_Departments', 'Starting.');
        $positions = Auth::user()->jobs()->find($jobId)->departments;
        Clockwork::endEvent('List_Default_Departments', 'Done.');
        return Response::json($positions->toArray());
    }
}
```

Note: There is a different between `$job->departments()` (returns Builder object to create more complex queries) and `$job->departments` (returns Collection object directly).

Also if you would like to get the list of jobs with all related departments you can always call:

```
$jobs = Auth::user()->jobs()->with('departments')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's helpful, however afaik the find() function looks for the index value of $jobId against the primary key, however $jobId is non-unique and not the primary key (it is, however, unique for that user).

Comment: Ok, fine. Anyway `Auth::user()->jobs()->where('job_id', $jobId)->with('departments')->get();` should work I guess.